Is there any difference between abduction and induction in Bayesian terms?
In abduction we take some observations and try to find the hypothesis that best explains them.
In Bayesian terms this sounds like finding the Maximum A Posteriori (MAP) estimate. To a Bayesian, "best" means "most likely." If we combine this with a Minimum Description Length (MDL) prior distribution, then in Bayesian terms abduction seems to be the process of finding the shortest hypothesis that fully explains the data. Abduction is essentially just what Bayesian inference does, no more and no less.
Bayesian inference is also typically taken to be a model of induction. In Bayesian terms, induction is also a matter of finding the MAP estimate, which with a MDL prior would again be the shortest hypothesis that fully explains the data. It appears that abduction, Bayesian inference, and induction are all the same thing.
Is there any example of induction, or any example of abduction, that does not simply boil down to finding a MAP estimate?
What I see is that listed examples of induction typically focus on the formation of scientific theories, like the theory of gravity, whereas examples of abduction tend to focus on particular events, like figuring out where someone was last night. From a Bayesian perspective these two scenarios are treated in basically the same way. A Theory of Gravity is evaluated by how well it explains the data and how concise it is... and A Theory of Where You Were Last Night is also evaluated by how well it explains the data and how concise it is. If the focus on scientific theories vs the focus on particular events is the only real difference between induction and abduction, it seems arbitrary, when we can think about both kinds of things using the same tools (MAP estimation).

One can treat special cases of abduction in Bayesianism, but it does not make it expressible in Bayesian terms, let alone "the same thing". That those terms do not distinguish it from induction and reduce best to most likely are not good signs either. Your 'argument' is circular: "to a Bayesian" A is B, therefore, A is B "in Bayesian terms". Applications of abduction to theory building are easy to find. "It is tempting, if the only tool you have is a hammer, to treat everything as if it were a nail" Maslow.

Help! I've been abducted by Bayesians!

@Conifold "and reduce best to most likely..." are you saying you favor some interpretation of induction or abduction under which best is not most likely?

So do you, "likely" may make no sense and "best" is judged on other grounds. Screws are not tightened with a hammer.

@Conifold Under what circumstances would you say "likely" makes no sense and "best" is judged on other grounds? We always have subjective credences that allow us to talk about likelihood. Also, if someone favors a hypothesis even though honestly it's not the most likely, I think this would normally be pathological rather than ideal reasoning. For instance, favoring a hypothesis because it is popular or because of wishful thinking. (Technically in Bayesian inference we're not just concerned with MAP but with all hypotheses - we don't just pick one, though in many cases that's close enough.)

This is a great question that deserves a full answer

And, now it has one

With induction, you are often trying to figure out what’s most likely in the future. With abduction, you are often trying to figure out what best explains something that already occurred.
Practically though, there seems to be no difference for reasons you mentioned already. This is because whether you are trying to explain historical data, or predicting future data, the best theory is often taken to be the one that is shortest/simplest that can explain all data. Solomonoff claimed to “solve” the problem of induction by formalizing Occam’s razor in Bayesian terms where the best hypothesis is simply the shortest algorithm used to explain all the data.

That's how I approach programming.

Caveat re your "Solomonoff claimed to “solve” the problem of induction by formalizing Occam’s razor in Bayesian terms", if Solomonoff's universal priors already 'solved' the problem of induction, why did he still need Bayesian terms to update the priors to arrive at their posteriors?...

Not to say that he actually did “solve” the problem of induction, but why does Bayesian updating imply the lack of a solution? @DoubleKnot

Since his solution is claimed to be 'universal' meaning applicable everywhere anytime, so why you need to mention Bayesian terms, which always means updating the prior to form the posterior, as if it's not already good enough and universally applicable to 'solve' the same original problem of induction as you claimed?...

@DoubleKnot Bayesianism by itself doesn't tell you what prior probabilities to use, hence the problem of the priors. Solomonoff came up with a reasonable way to assign those priors.

My above query is about those Solomonoff priors which are also called universal. Since you already got the priors which are applicable universally everywhere, why you still need to update them somewhere near you? Recall you don't need to update Newton's universal gravity anywhere you go, at least on earth surface...

@DoubleKnot I'm not sure what you mean here. The priors tell you what probabilities you should possess as a matter of degree of belief prior to any evidence taken into account. Of course, after evidence is taken into account, these can be updated

Recall the way you get these priors are essentially through Occam's razor MDL formalism which are supposed to apply everywhere as you also seem to intuit, so even there're any new real evidence you're thrown into, the razor still continues to apply necessarily...

@DoubleKnot the razor can apply between hypotheses that explain the same piece of evidence. But evidence would also rule out certain hypotheses that you cannot rule out apriori.

Then you perhaps better contemplate why your thrown evidences like a sword or bullet seem more powerful than a razor? If it turns out they're much more powerful, then it deductively implies the so called Solomonoff universal priors are mostly useless in the real world thrown Bayesian-like applications anyway? Btw, keep in mind that in Bayesianism, no hypothesis can be absolutely ruled out, just more or less probable regarding said evidences...

@DoubleKnot the razor applies to hypotheses that explain the same evidence. When considering prior probabilities, the razor applies to all. Once evidence is taken into account, some hypotheses are ruled out. But the razor still remains for all the hypotheses that explain that evidence. I see no issue in this process.

So you still see no issue in your above claim "Solomonoff claimed to “solve” the problem of induction by formalizing Occam’s razor in Bayesian terms", when the razor meets the sword?...

@DoubleKnot It can be constituted as a solution to the problem of induction in the sense that an inductive explanation is often simpler and explains the data just as well as a more complicated, less unified, and usually more ad hoc explanation
